# Error] cannot pass objects of non-trivially-copyable type 'std::string {aka class std::basic_string<char>}' through '...'

Tags: c++, arrays, string, numbers

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string>
main()
{
int br_el[6],i;
std::string qr_naziv[6];

    qr_naziv[0]="Bath tub";

    qr_naziv[1]="Sink";

    qr_naziv[2]="Washing machine";

    qr_naziv[3]="Toilet";

    qr_naziv[4]="Kitchen sink";

    qr_naziv[5]="Dish washer";


for(i=0;i<6;i++)
    {

        printf("Input the number for %s =",qr_naziv[i]);\\here lies the problem

scanf("%d",&br_el[i]);
}
```

This program is much longer, so I shortened it..
The thing is, I will enter numbers for array `br_el[6]`, and I want it to show me for what object I am entering the number! 
So when I try to compile it gives me the error:"[Error] cannot pass objects of non-trivially-copyable type 'std::string {aka class std::basic_string}' through '...'"
I tried to declare `string qr_naziv[6];` but the string didn't even bold so it didn't work, so I googled and found out another way (`std::string qr_naziv[6];`).

Answer (score 57, accepted):

Well, C functions are not acquainted with C++ structures. You should do the following:

```
...
for(i = 0; i < 6; i++) {
    printf("Input the number for %s =", qr_naziv[i].c_str());
    scanf("%d", &br_el[i]);
}
...
```

Notice the call to the method [`c_str()`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/c_str) on the each `std::string qr_naziv[i]`, which returns a *`const char *` to a null-terminated character array with data equivalent to those stored in the string* -- a C-like string.

**Edit**:
And, of course, since you're working with C++, the most appropriate to do is to use the stream operators insertion `<<` and extraction `>>`, as duly noted by @MatsPetersson. In your case, you could do the following modification:

```
# include <iostream>
...
for(i = 0; i < 6; i++) {
    std::cout << "Input the number for " << qr_naziv[i] << " =";
    std::cin >> br_el[i];
}
...
```

Comment: Or, use `cin >> ` and `cout << ` style C++ constructs, instead of C style code.

Comment: I will consider your advice! :)

Comment: Can i solve this problem with overloading of an type-casting operator?

Comment: @SuB Calling `c_str()` may be held as coercing the `std::string qr_naziv[i]` into a C string. However, there is no explicit syntatic sugar for that in C++, as C strings are typed `char *`, and a `char *` is not a constructor that would implement an overload with a `std::string` as argument.